# LIMIT for DISTINCT values of column in WHERE clause not no of rows - SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, limit

Let's say I've two tables, named `customers` and `transactions`, the sample data is as follows:

**customers**

```
+----+---------------------------------+------------+------------+
| id | company                         | first_name | last_name  |
+----+---------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 1  | Mus Donec Dignissim LLC         | Tad        | Hoffman    |
| 2  | Aliquet Magna A LLP             | Aretha     | Wilkinson  |
| 3  | Mauris Aliquam Foundation       | Cooper     | Goff       |
| 4  | Quisque Libero Lacus Associates | Fulton     | Beard      |
| 5  | At Risus Ltd                    | Simone     | Perkins    |
| 6  | Quam Corp.                      | Hayfa      | Hernandez  |
| 7  | Vel Quam Dignissim Associates   | Linus      | Walker     |
| 8  | A Enim Suspendisse Consulting   | Emi        | Wallace    |
| 9  | Placerat Industries             | Cody       | Mendez     |
| 10 | Nunc Limited                    | Yasir      | Cunningham |
+----+---------------------------------+------------+------------+
```

**transactions**

```
+----+-----------+-------------+------+
| id | form_type | customer_id | due  |
+----+-----------+-------------+------+
| 1  | invoice   | 9           | 1.08 |
| 2  | payment   | 1           | 6.32 |
| 3  | invoice   | 7           | 9.42 |
| 4  | payment   | 9           | 3.58 |
| 5  | invoice   | 7           | 5.35 |
| 6  | payment   | 3           | 5.42 |
| 7  | invoice   | 9           | 5.32 |
| 8  | invoice   | 9           | 9.62 |
| 9  | invoice   | 10          | 1.40 |
| 10 | invoice   | 2           | 3.72 |
+----+-----------+-------------+------+
```

I want to select all the transactions based on some condition (look into SQL below) for 3 customers sorted by alphabetical order of their `company`, `first_name` and `last_name` respectively.
So, the idea is that in output there can be more than 3 rows returned as one particular customer can have more than one matching transaction but there should only be 3 customers in total.

I know the SQL below is obviously incorrectly limiting on no of rows instead of no of distinct customers for the wanted data, but here it is to make the question clear:

```
SELECT 
  t.id AS trans_id,
  c.id AS customer_id,
  c.company,
  c.first_name,
  c.last_name,
  t.due
FROM `customers` AS c, `transactions` AS t
WHERE t.due > 0 AND t.form_type = 'invoice' AND c.id = t.customer_id
ORDER BY c.company, c.first_name, c.last_name
LIMIT 0, 3
```

I've tried ways using `INNER JOIN` or Subquery but either they return incorrect data or the SQL doesn't seem quite right to me. I'm seeking for some expert solution on this.

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9d4f0/4/0)

**UPDATE**
I forgot to mention that I can't use `IN` for a subquery result, as MySQL version denies it. 
*This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'.*
Please provide alternative.

Comment: i am not following you , can you please place how  the result table as a picture ! so i can help u ?

Comment: @AhmedShahin You can check [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9d4f0/4/0). I'm not getting correct data.

Comment: yes , i want to help you , but i need you to put a picture of what the expected data to appear so i can help u

Comment: like let's say you have done the query , what the result you expect to be in table ?

Comment: @AhmedShahin I got you, you want me to prepare output table, but I'm lazy doing that. Here in question we've limited data, so we can surely prepare output result but for real life data it'll take a lot of time. I've provided you the logic for the end result and I think I'm clear in that.

Comment: rmalviya What @AhmedShahin is saying is that if you provide the desired output for this example it will clarify what you want. AhmedShahin I believe he wants all rows from the query but only for the first three customers, regardless of number of transactions per customer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
SELECT 
  t.id AS trans_id,
  c.id AS customer_id,
  c.company,
  c.first_name,
  c.last_name,
  t.due
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT c.*
  FROM customers AS c
  INNER JOIN transactions AS t ON t.customer_id = c.id
  WHERE t.due > 0
  AND t.form_type = 'invoice'
  ORDER BY c.company, c.first_name, c.last_name
  LIMIT 3
) AS c
INNER JOIN transactions AS t ON t.customer_id = c.id
WHERE t.due > 0
AND t.form_type = 'invoice'
ORDER BY c.company, c.first_name, c.last_name;
```

In case someone with a later version of MySQL finds this question, with MySQL 8.0 you can use common table expressions which allows one to remove the duplication from the query. Query from https://stackoverflow.com/a/52137146/495319

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT
    t.id AS trans_id,
    c.id AS customer_id,
    c.company,
    c.first_name,
    c.last_name,
    t.due,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY c.company, c.first_name, c.last_name) AS rn
  FROM customers AS c
  INNER JOIN transactions AS t ON t.customer_id = c.id
  WHERE t.due > 0 AND t.form_type = 'invoice'
)
SELECT * FROM cte WHERE rn <= 3;
```

Comment: I've tried similar queries. Can you eliminate row with `trans_id = 4` in your result as `transactions.id = 4` is not fulfilling the condition of `form_type = invoice`.

Comment: Good point. I've updated it. Not that happy because it repeats the `WHERE` clauses. I see you've updated the question to say you can't use LIMIT in subqueries or something? I tried this with MySQL 5.6 and it works for me.

Comment: I see that mine is essentially the same as @MadhurBhaiya's answer, except that his unnecessarily joins `customers` again.

Comment: Seems working. I've tried similar ways but as I had mentioned its bit messy. From 2 similar answers I guess this is the way to do it. Try to clean it up if possible.

Comment: I suspect you could do it cleanly with SQL window functions or something if you were using e.g. PostgreSQL, but I have no experience with them, so wouldn't be able to show you what it would look like, and of course changing your DBMS might be too much effort.

Comment: See this for a much simpler query that's possible with `common table expressions` (unfortunately not supported by MySQL 5.x, but I think should work in MySQL 8.0). https://stackoverflow.com/a/52137146/495319

Comment: Although, I appreciate @MadhurBhaiya's answer too, I accept your answer for showing another approach using common table expressions. First approach in your answer is where from my question originated, duplication of where clauses and two time join of same tables.

Comment: So, also for counting results only, we have to apply same query with difference of only `COUNT(*)` in SELECT list?

Comment: Yes `SELECT COUNT(*)`, in the outer query.

Answer (score 1):

**Approach 1** - If needed to use a single query, and getting the results in required format directly:

```
SELECT 
  t.id AS trans_id,
  c.id AS customer_id,
  c.company,
  c.first_name,
  c.last_name,
  t.due
FROM transactions AS t 
INNER JOIN (SELECT c2.*
             FROM customers AS c2 
             INNER JOIN transactions AS t2 ON t2.customer_id = c2.id 
             WHERE t2.due > 0 AND t2.form_type = 'invoice' 
             GROUP BY c2.id 
             ORDER BY c2.company, c2.first_name, c2.last_name
             LIMIT 0, 3
           ) AS c ON c.id = t.customer_id 
WHERE t.due > 0 AND 
      t.form_type = 'invoice' 
ORDER BY c.company, c.first_name, c.last_name
```

**Approach 2** - Using a more efficient query (reducing `WHERE` conditions), and then bifurcating the query results using application code, to get in required format:

```
SELECT 
  c.id AS customer_id,
  c.company,
  c.first_name,
  c.last_name, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(t.id,':',t.due)) AS trans_details 
FROM customers AS c 
INNER JOIN transactions AS t 
WHERE t.due > 0 AND 
      t.form_type = 'invoice' 
GROUP BY c.id 
ORDER BY c.company, c.first_name, c.last_name
```

Now, in the application code, you can bifurcate the `trans_details`:

```
// $query_results is the sql result rows obtained in associative mode
foreach ($query_results as $key => $row) {

    // Get all separate transactions into array
    $trans_details = explode(',', $row['trans_details']);

    foreach ($trans_details as $trans) { 
        $temp = explode(':', $trans);

        // Add trans_id and due to get desired format
        $query_results[$key]['trans_id'] = $temp[0];
        $query_results[$key]['due'] = $temp[1];
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention that I can't use IN for a subquery result, as MySQL version denies it. `This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'`. Please provide alternative.

Comment: @rmalviya What is your MySQL version ?

Comment: 5.7.23-0ubuntu0.16.04.1-log

Comment: @rmalviya I have also converted your original query's Implicit joins to much better and efficient Explicit Joins

Comment: @rmalviya fixed. just a comma

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179272/discussion-between-madhur-bhaiya-and-rmalviya).

Comment: Looks promising. But as I said in my original question its putting same conditions multiple times, can you clean it up little bit? Also, the order is not correct.

Comment: @rmalviya fixed the order; that's the best cleaned up solution - if you are looking for a single query based solution. There is one another approach possible using `GROUP_CONCAT` and then in your application code, you explode the results to get data in required formats.

Comment: Please post that too.